# Etherdelta error when calling withdraw, deposit or transfer

Tags: etherdelta, address.transfer, error

Everything I do with Etherdelta. I get an error. I really don't know where is it coming from.

It is pending the whole time.

Comment: The ethereum network is going through a high volume with above 20k pending transactions, you have to use a higher fee if you want your transactions be mined timely.